# Como deserializar JSON usando Gson com lista genérica?

Tags: java, json, genéricos, gson, desserialização

Preciso deserializar o JSON para uma lista genérica, porém estou tendo um erro que acredito que seja na conversão:

Chamada do método:

```
AtualizarJSON at = (AtualizarJSON) DeserializaConsulta(AtualizarJSON.class, resultadoJSON);
```

Método:

```
private <T> List<T> DeserializaConsulta(Class<T> tipo, String resultadoJSON) throws JSONException {
        if (resultadoJSON != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(resultadoJSON, tipo));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Requisição no WS:

```
private String ConsultarOuBaixarAtualizacoes(String urlT) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlT);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            conn.getResponseCode();

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            reader.read(buffer);

            return new String(buffer);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   126

Acredito que esta solução não é a ideal, pois deve haver uma forma de resolver este problema setando os tipos como já vi em alguns exemplos, mas não consegui encontrar exemplos para este caso em que passo o tipo por parâmetro.

Comment: Poderia colocar uma amostra do JSON?

Comment: Eu já tive problemas com Gson e lista genérica, mas não lembro bem o que era, acho que não é possível fazer do jeito que está querendo (posso estar enganado, amanhã eu vejo meu projeto). Entretanto sua mensagem de erro indica um problema antes mesmo da tentativa de conversão do JSON, aparentemente você ele foi formado errado, tente dar uma conferida por erros nele. Como ele foi gerado?

Comment: Vou por o retorno dele aqui, provavelmente é isto mesmo, ele vem corretamente mas o final dele vem um monte de caracteres esquisitos

Comment: Coloque a amostra dentro da sua pergunta, porque está quebrando o layout do site hehe. Provalvemente isso deve ser algum problema de encoding. Tente verificar se o encoding da resposta é o mesmo que seu cliente espera. E acredito que acertando isso nem precise usar o `setLenient`.

Comment: @Math não consigo por a amostra la, não consigo editar =/... coloquei um print do retorno via navegador, ele não retorna essa string ae... testei em 2 navegadores.

Comment: @Wakim certo verei isso! Valeu!

Comment: @Wakim pode verificar a requisição se tem algo errado? Adicionei a pergunta.

Comment: Eu acredito que seja o `buffer`. Porque não usa um `BufferedReader` para ler todas as linhas (usando um `StringBuilder`)? Porque provavelmente você está tendo uma `String` com 2048 caracteres onde 60% é lixo (dado antigo da memória).

Comment: @Wakim poe como resposta! Vi um exemplo assim e não consegui fazer. Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que esses caracteres inválidos venham do modo como está lendo, não como do encoding como eu supus no início.

Quando você aloca um vetor de char com 2048 posições e usa para ler a resposta. Provavelmente está com 60% de caracteres sendo valores anteriores existente na memória heap. E isso causa o problema de *parsing* do GSON.

Recomendo ler a resposta do servidor usando um `BufferedReader`. Lendo todas as linhas até o término da resposta.

O código seria:

```
private String ConsultarOuBaixarAtualizacoes(String urlT) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlT);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        conn.getResponseCode();

        is = conn.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Le cada linha da resposta ate o final
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to com.universo91.catalogo91_android.dto.AtualizarJSON agora o erro é gerado na conversão! Ou seja, funcionou mas ainda preciso de algo que devo ter feito errado nesta conversão!

Comment: Ah... O erro é que o método `Deserializar` sempre vai devolver uma lista. Não apenas um objeto `AtualizarJSON`. Refatore o método para retornar diretamente `new Gson().fromJson(resultadoJSON, tipo)` ou Troque a variável para `List<AtualizarJSON>` e pegue o primeiro elemento.

Comment: Teria que refatorar mesmo, porém não deveria voltar uma lista com apenas um objeto? Se for fazer isso, o método praticamente se inválida, pois o motivo do List<T> é o de voltar 1 ou mais... qual seu conselho pra resolver?

Comment: Se é pra ser genérico, melhor atribuir o retorno a uma lista e pegar o primeiro elemento, sem mexer no método.

Comment: O erro esta na chamada do método ao lado de fora, na linha onde declara a variável "at"